# the tkinter button does not work in ubuntu

Tags: class, ubuntu, tkinter, button, command

I can't make the button work, it works as it should on the windows, why doesn't it work in ubuntu?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys

class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.attributes("-alpha", 1)
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title("CPU-RAM usage monitor bar")

        self.set_ui()

    def set_ui(self):
        exit_but = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=lambda: self.app_exit)
        exit_but.pack(fill=tk.X)


    def app_exit(self):
        self.destroy()
        sys.exit()


root = Application()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your lambda isn't calling a function. `self.app_exit` is not the same as `self.app_exit()`.

Comment: however, the button remains inactive

Comment: The button should be active, in that you can click it. It won't do anything, however, since your lambda doesn't do anything. It references a function, but it doesn't _call_ the function.

Comment: if I don't need to pass, I can call the function without lambda:
exit_but = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.app_exit)

Comment: it's all for self.overrideredirect(True)
I commented it and everything works fine

Comment: Yes, the more correct way is to not use lambda: `command=self.app_exit`. If you're using lambda, the body of the lambda must call `self.app_exit`: `lambda: self.app_exit()`